# Is it possible to put one E0 voice signal directly into a STM1 frame

Tags: digital-communications

I've been going through STM1 frame structure recently.

Is it possible to put a single E0(64kbps) voice channel directly into a stm1 frame or should it be put sequentially into a E1 and then to an E2 and so on and finally an E4 into a STM1 frame.

I've done enough of googling but still couldn’t get it cleared.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to design something using the protocol or just configure some networking gear? If the latter it may be better on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm actually trying to design a DWDM, so to do that a prior knowledge of STM frames is required, so i got this doubt.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. SDH only support transport of E1 (2Mbit), DS1 (1.5Mbit), E3 (45Mbit), DS3 (36Mbit) - encapsulating those in low order VC12 or VC3, which are in turn encapsulated into a VC4. You can also encapsulate an E4 directly into a VC4.
Note that E1 and DS3 are the most common encapsulations. There are also a number of schemes to encapsulate Ethernet signals.
To transport an E0, you need to multiplex it into a E1 (European) or DS1 (North America) first using a PDH multiplexer.
Some more details [here](http://www.rhyshaden.com/sdh.htm).

In your case, you would pack 31 E0's into an E1 using a PDH multiplexer, then 21 E1's into VC3 and 3 VC3's into a VC4. There are other ways too - you can use a PDH multiplexer to go from E1 to E4 and then encapsulate that directly into a VC4. It all depends on what equipment you are using.

Note btw that your 64kb signal isn't generally called an E0 - the PDH hierarchy starts with E1. Normally, the 64kbit is just called a 'channel'. Each channel fills one of 31 time slots in an E1. See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-carrier).

Answer (score -1):

you can, as long as you follow the STM1 frame structure. 64KBps G.703 is equivalent to a STM VC4 block. E1 and E3 frames are converted into their individual 64KBps G.703 subframes and converted to VC4 blocks (there are some timing conformance to be made).

[image]

Comment: That's not correct. You can only encapsulate an E4, of or a number of low order VC3 and/or VC12, contains E3/DS3 or E1/DS1 respectively.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been: That's not correct. You can only encapsulate an E4 or a number of low order VC3 and/or VC12 containing E3/DS3 or E1/DS1 respectively.

Comment: To explain a bit more about why a STM1 block isn't a E0 channel: the E1 is mapped into a VC12.  As part of that process, the data a made synchronous by using a pointer and bit stuffing. As such, the location of an individual E0 channel is not fixed within the STM-1 frame. This is a general issue with PDH signals and the precise reason why SDH was developed. In SDH you can extract the lowest order signal without de multiplexing. With PDH, you have to completely de multiplex your signal to get to the lowest order channel.